# how to run shell on a remote server with root priviledge

Tags: ssh, root, remote

I want to execute a shell script on a remote server, and the script should be run by root with no password required (or use `sudo` in the script).
Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: i tried ssh, but i don't know how to run as a root.

Comment: Do you have root access on the remote machine?

Comment: i have the root access remote machine. but i don't want to hard code the password in my local script because the password may be modified.

Comment: See also [Copying protected files between servers in one line?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27890)

Answer (score 6):

Beside solutions with `sudo`, that can be script-friendly be configured (no extra password-prompt for specific commands) or [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) solutions which are not easy to do secure, I suggest the usage of ssh public-key authorization with the command= restriction.

For this, you need to enable password-less login to the root user if not yet done (`PermitRootLogin without-password` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) and add your (or better a special for this case created) ssh public key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` with a command= argument like described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34490/15241).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to place your root password in script.

### Solution A

suid your script on the server , and make it read / executable only by root or your user group.

```
chmod 4750 script.sh
chgrp your_group script.sh
```

Don't forget to join your user into that group.

And you do `ssh user@XXXX '/path/to/script.sh'` to execute the script.

### Solution B

Create a SSH key , and copy public key to the remote server.
This way you'll have to login as root , but also password-less.
(Remeber to decrypt your private key with openssl)

It's very dangerous if you lost your private key.

Answer (score 0):

**The save solution without root users**

*on the client generate an ssh-key*

client:  `ssh-keygen`

*copy it to the server*

server: `mkdir ~/.ssh`

client: `scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub serveruser@server:~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

*allow sudo without password for your user*

server:

```
visudo
    serveruser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/foo /usr/sbin/bar
```

*now you can run commands like that*

client: `ssh serveruser@server 'sudo foo && bar'`

*//some servers my require `ssh -t ...` to use sudo*