# Restricted ssh remote execution with arguments

Tags: shell-script, ssh, users, remote-control

I need to enable remote execution of a shell script on a server, but deny all other access. The script is a toggle that accepts a single parameter (on/off/status). [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34486/adding-a-user-who-can-only-execute-scripts-remotely) comes close to answering my question, but while it works to run scripts remotely, I still can't pass arguments. Is there a way to do this without making a new shell account for each possible argument?

Basically, I want to be able to run on my remote server:

```
myclient$ ssh remotecontrol@myserver on
myclient$ ssh remotecontrol@myserver off
myclient$ ssh remotecontrol@myserver status
```

And have this correspond to:

```
myserver$ ./myscript.sh on
myserver$ ./myscript.sh off
myserver$ ./myscript.sh status
```

Arcege's response in the linked article could do this, but it doesn't work as a one-liner in a shell script.

---

**SOLUTION DETAILS:**

```
# useradd -Urms /home/remotecontrol/shell.sh remotecontrol
```

Added the following line to `~remotecontrol/.ssh/authorized_keys` to disable remote login:

```
no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa [...public key...] remoteuser@remotehost
```

Added the following shell script as `~remotecontrol/shell.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case "$2" in
    on)
        echo 'Command: on'
        ;;
    off)
        echo 'Command: off'
        ;;
    status)
        echo 'Command: status'
        ;;
    *)
        echo 'Invalid command'
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a custom shell [as suggested by Arcege](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34507/14034) [and 2bc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34541/14034), then that shell will receive the command which the user intends to execute as an argument because the shell is invoked like this:

```
shellname -c the_original_command
```

So ignore the `-c` (that your `$1`) and find the command in `$2`. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$2" in
    on)
        do something
        ;;
    off)
        do something else
        ;;
    *)
        echo "wrong command name!" >&2
        exit 1
esac
```

If you use a forced command [as suggested by Coren](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34490/14034) then you will find the command that the user intended to invoke in the environment variable `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`. You can use a script similar to the one above.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I've updated my question to add a section with the full solution.