# How to limit users permissions to only use mysql

Tags: permissions, account-restrictions

Is it possible to create users (non-sudoers) that can only use the command "mysql" ? or set of commands ?

Context: I have a server hosting a mysql database. I want to give some users the rights to connect to the server via SSH but only so they can use the mysql client.

I am using a the Amazon linux AMI

Ps : 
Using the command option in the authorized_keys file is not a correct solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a user who can only execute scripts remotely](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34486/adding-a-user-who-can-only-execute-scripts-remotely)

Comment: There are some similarities with "Adding a user who can only execute scripts remotely" but is it not the same question.

Comment: Why is the "command" option in `.authorized_keys` not a correct solution?

Comment: The command option is used to force the launch of a command when a ssh connection is made.

Comment: Right, and it also tells the SSH server to ignore any other command given — so if you specify the MySQL client as the command in `.authorized_keys`, that would give you the result you're after, unless I've misunderstood your requirement!

Comment: Ok I know understand that my question is very badly written.
I need users to be able to connect to the server and locally(thourgh the ssh tunnel) use the port 3306 so they can access the database through their own client. In doing so, I don't want to give them any extra rights.

Should I delete this question and post a new one or rewrite this one?

Comment: Ah right, you want to allow them to set up an SSH tunnel to port 3306, is that correct? You should rewrite this question, and ping the two people who have answered (by commenting on their answers) to notify them that the question has changed.

Comment: Actually, thanks to your questions, I realized that my issue was http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14312/how-to-restrict-an-ssh-user-to-only-allow-ssh-tunneling

Comment: Excellent, in that case you should probably delete this question!

Comment: It turns out I cannot delete this question because its under moderator attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to add a user with restricted privileges, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/767415/limit-user-to-execute-selective-commands-linux) for more details.

On the other hand you can also limit his login shell,  for example

```
useradd -s $(which mysql) whatshisname
```

This makes his default shell mysql

Comment: Thank you. The post was interesting but dealing with sudoers permissions. Sorry Alice, I don't know how I could leverage the default shell options for my issue, could you tell me more?

Comment: Hi hugo, may I ask why you need to make his login shell mysql only? a normal user has pretty limited privileges to begin with.

Comment: This was my initial thought as well, but the <code>mysql</code> UI allows the execution of arbitrary shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

Hugo.

You can create an inbound rule in your vpc security group to allow remote connections to port 3306, which is used from mysql. In this way your users will bi able to access the mysql via mysql-client installed on their computers without the need to connect via ssh.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want them to use SSH. Opening port 3306 is a dangerous solution.